# Which formula to calculate $P(A\cap B)$?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics, discrete-mathematics, bayes-theorem

Trying to solve discrete probability exercises I always don't know which formula I should use to calculate $P(A \cap B)$.
I have 3 choices :

1) $P(A) \cdot P(B)$

2) $P(A|B) \cdot P(B)$ (from conditional probability formula)

3) Do some calculations in order to use DeMorgan's laws

I don't know when use 1) instead of 2) or 3) and viceversa.
For example :
The probability that a student, randomly chosen among the undergraduates in biology, after the first exam session doesn't pass the chemistry test is 0.4; the probability the student is from a scientific high school is 0.3, the probability that a student is from a scientific high school and she passed the test is 0.25. What is the probability that a student is not from a scientific high school and she didn't pass the chemistry test?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It will be more likely to get an answer if you show us that you made an effort.

Comment: (1) If $A$ and $B$ are independent. (2) If $P(A\,|\,B)$ and $P(B)$ are both known. (3) If quantities to the right of the $=$-sign in DeMorgan's Law are known. // Do you have a specific problem in mind?

Comment: Please use specific problems to illustrate your question further. For example, adding here a question where you have struggled with the above choice will be of great benefit.

Comment: You left out $P(A)+P(B)-P(A\cup B).$

Comment: I just updated the question with a problem

Answer (score 1):

There's no magic rule when to use one or the other... you use whichever is most helpful, which you'll get a sense for as you gain more experience with this type of problem.

(Other than, as BruceET pointed out, that the first formula is valid if and only if $A$ and $B$ are independent.)

In your problem, we aren't given independence, and we don't have the probability of one event given another, but we do have the probability of some negations, so De Morgan looks like the best bet. Let $A$ be "the student is not from a scientific high school," and $B$ "the student didn't pass the test." We want $P(A \cap B)$. We have $P(B) = 0.4$, $P(\neg A) = 0.3$, and $P(\neg A \cap \neg B) = 0.25$. Looking at the quantities we know, it seems most promising to use $$\begin{align}
P(A \cap B) &= 1 - P(\neg A \cup \neg B) \\&= 1 - P(\neg B) - P(\neg A) + P(\neg A \cap \neg B) \\&= P(B) - P(\neg A) + P(\neg A \cap \neg B) \\&= 0.4 - 0.3 + 0.25 \\&=0.35 \end{align}$$

Comment: I just updated the question with a problem, thank you

Comment: @FBIT I've updated my answer.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! I'm posting the solution provided by the professor.We randomly choose one student and we define the events A"the student passed chemistry test",B ="The student is from a scientific high school". Looking at the exercise, we deduce that P(Ac) = 0.4, P(B) = 0.3, P(A \ B) = 0.25. We want to find P(Ac \ Bc). With De Morgan's Laws, Ac \ Bc = (A [ B)c so:
P(Ac \Bc) = 1 P(A[B)=1 P(A) P(B)+P(A\B)
= P(Ac) P(B)+P(A\B)=0.4 0.3+0.25=0.35.

Comment: @FBIT I'm sorry, but I don't follow that solution. To start, where do we get $P(B) = 0.3$? Also, what does your notation [ and \ mean?

Comment: I wrote wrong,check again the question I updated. \ stands for intersection

Comment: @FBIT Changed my answer to reflect new information you gave. With the new information, De Morgan indeed looks promising.

Comment: Why I can't use P(A|B)×P(B)? I can calculate P(A|B) because I have P(A) and P(B).

Comment: @FBIT My first instinct was De Morgan, but that doesn't mean other methods won't work. Try doing it that way and post it here.

Comment: So can we say that P(A|B)×P(B) always works?

Comment: @FBIT Yes. $P(A) \times P(B)$ requires independence, but the other two formulas you mentioned always work (whether there is independence or not).